# Showing HTML page with CSS attached in a WebView

Tags: android, css, webview

I'm trying to load a web page in a `WebView`, but when the page is retrieved I lost all style information, maybe the CSS file is not used properly in my web view.

For retrieving data I'm using `HTTP POST` in this way:

```
public void postData() throws IOException, ClientProtocolException {
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1", "parameter1"));  
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param2", "parameter2"));

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL_STRING);  
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);  
    String data = new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(response);
    WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadData(data, "text/html", "utf-8");
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Where's your CSS? Is it in a separate file?

Comment: In the code of the html page I found this string `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/maindir/css/sites.css">`

Comment: Can you confirm `/maindir/css/sites.css` exists / has data in it?

Comment: of course! there are data in it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the relative path `href="/maindir/css/sites.css"`:

**Solution 1:**  (change at server)

In case you have access to web-server try using full path in `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/maindir/css/sites.css">`. So instead of `/maindir/css/sites.css` you will have `http://your.domain.com/maindir/css/sites.css`

**Solution 2:** (change at client)

Instead of `mWebView.loadData(data, "text/html", "utf-8");` use method [loadDataWithBaseURL (String baseUrl, String data, String mimeType, String encoding, String historyUrl)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) the `baseUrl` string will be used in order to make relative path to work.

Result will be something like:

`mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://your.domain.com/", data, "text/html", "utf-8", null);`

Comment: not really depends if you decide to change the server or the client... I edit the post to make it clear!

Comment: Thank you @madlymad. I use the solution 2. Now it works good :)

Comment: For futur googlers : Don't forget the trailing / at the end of your base url : "http://your.domain.com/" works, "http://your.domain.com" doesn't.